# hook_page_alter called once

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I have a Drupal 7 theme which is a Bootstrap child theme.

In my version of page.vars.php, I have a `THEME_page_alter()` call which runs only once until I do a clear cache. Other hooks such as `THEME_process_page` or `THEME_preprocess_page` are called each time I reload the page.

A second theme, with the same page_alter hook works just fine and is called each page-reload without the need for a clear-cache first.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Are the 2 themes tested on the same site?

Comment: Yes, they are on a multi-domain setup, but all running from the same Drupal instance.

Comment: I suspect it is due to the page cache...

Comment: Why would the output change though? Surely it would cache the same result as the first run?

Comment: As I remember, rendering array is cached if you enable page cache. But preprocess function still work because the cache is made before the preprocess function.

Answer (score 0):

Theme settings are specific to each theme. Go to /admin/appearance/settings/yourtheme and check for any theme-specific caching options. I can't tell you exactly what the options would be because that depends on your theme.

Comment: I couldn't see anything of relevance in there. The thing is that the logic that runs the first time around in `THEME_page_alter()` works correctly, but then it's not like it caches the correct logic on the subsequent page load. It seems to not run at all, and displays a region that I specifically want to hide (unset)